# How to retrieve grouped records with specified last record columns

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

| id | user_id | category | subcategory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 243 | credit | purchase |
| 2 | 243 | credit | renewal |
| 3 | 243 | credit | purchase |
| 4 | 243 | credit | renewal |
| 5 | 243 | revenue | recognition |
| 6 | 245 | credit | purchase |
| 7 | 245 | credit | renewal |
| 8 | 248 | revenue | recognition |
| 9 | 249 | credit | purchase |
| 10 | 249 | revenue | recognition |
| 11 | 250 | revenue | recognition |
| 12 | 250 | credit | purchase |

Given a table that stores a user's transactions with different transaction categories and sub categories , I want to return only records with a specific category as the last record for a user.
In the example above,I would like to retrieve users who have their last transaction category as revenue and sub category as recognition. The query should return user_id 248 and 250 since they have category=revenue and subcategory=recognition as their last records

Comment: The query should return 248 and 249

Comment: Sounds like a groupwise-max problem; see the tag I added.

Comment: What defines "*last transaction category*'?

Comment: It would help if you posted your table schema and the query you tried.  A dbfiddle would be even better.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version? show output for `SELECT VERSION();`..

Comment: *I would like to retrieve users who have their **last transaction** category as revenue and sub category as recognition* Define what transaction should be treated as "last" - transaction with greatest `id`?

Comment: @Akina The Mysql Version is 5.7.37. The last record is the transaction with the greatest ID

Comment: If so then use subquery which gets maximal `id` for each `user_id`. In outer query get according row and test it against your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.user_id
FROM table t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(id) id
       FROM table
       GROUP BY user_id ) t2 USING (id)
WHERE (t1.category, t1.subcategory) = ('revenue', 'recognition')
```